# Page recompile on code change

Tags: asp.net, class, compilation, html, app-code

I have .net aspx page. Generally I write my classes separately in app_code. But this page uses a class which is required by only this page. Sort of a temporary class. So I wrote it in this page. If I make any changes to this page (not the class) just the vb part of it , will that affect the entire site. I mean would it recompile the entire site because there was a class involved? If you need more info, please ask. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "VB part" is also a DLL. So the website will be recompiled.
The recompilation will not happen only in modifications on HTML, Javascript and CSS files